# CSS 3 column layout, sidebars with flexible height, Code order for SEO: CONTENT-LEFT-RIGHT

Tags: html, css, height

I would like to get some advice on CSS. My goal is:

1. 3-column layout - left sidebar, main content, right sidebar
2. Sidebars have flexible height based on the content column height.
3. For SEO purposes, I need the PHP files with contents to be called in this order.

   1. Main content file
   2. Left sidebar file
   3. Right sidebar file

So the divs have to be order this way:

```
<div id="columns-container">
        <div id="content-bar">              
             <!-- PHP include of the content (middle bar) -->                                       
        </div>
        <div id="left-sidebar">             
            <!-- PHP include of the leftbar navigation -->                                          
        </div> 
        <div id="right-sidebar">            
            <!-- PHP include of the rightbar with ads and stuff -->                                     
        </div>          
</div>
```

If I were to call the files in order "left bar - content - right bar", that would be easy even for me. But this is a tall order for me.

So far, I have been able to create sidebars with minumum height, but I don't know how to extend them.

I got lost in the CSS and I think my solution is wrong, so I'd appreciate if somebody helped me build it from scratch and better.

Comment: If you weren’t cooking up such a DIV soup, but where using HTML5 elements like aside, article etc. to mark up your content more semantically, then the actual order of the content in the source woulnd’t even matter that much …

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the most popular "ready-to-use" layouts: [Holy Grail](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-liquid-layout-no-quirks-mode). It has everything that you asked for.